# Can you make a clock as a placeable block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft can you make a clock and then place it? I want to have it as an "Alarm clock" for my mansion.

Comment: If you want a "real" alarm clock in MineCraft, you can play around with the new [Light Sensor](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Light_sensor) and some [Note blocks](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Noteblock).

Comment: How could you do that? With redstone repeaters?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the [Item Frame](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame).

> Maps show their contents, and compasses and clocks work as normal